# How do i view the "raw xml" output from nusoap?

Tags: php, xml, soap, nusoap

I have a generic function that I use to pass SOAP commands. I need to view the RAW XML data that is being ***sent*** to the server for diagnosing an error. How do i do that?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Never mind, this seems to be pretty close to the dot!

http://www.scottnichol.com/nusoapintro.htm

```
echo '<h2>Request</h2>';
echo '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars($client->request, ENT_QUOTES) . '</pre>';
echo '<h2>Response</h2>';
echo '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars($client->response, ENT_QUOTES) . '</pre>';

// Display the debug messages
echo '<h2>Debug</h2>';
echo '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars($client->debug_str, ENT_QUOTES) . '</pre>';
```

Answer (score 2):

While this is an old post i wanted to chip in with my own version of tzmatt answer.

```
class soapBug {

    /*
     * @var obj $debug client object
     * @var string $what Just a name for the header so you know
     * what you are looking at.
     */
    public function bug($debug, $what) {
        /* ive stayed with the original here, but you could look at
         * http://www.php.net/manual/en/tidy.repairstring.php to
         * output in clean xml.
         *
         * I just grab the line i need and paste
         * it into my IDE and let it format for me, works just as well
         * and no coding to fiddle with for something that wont be
         * permanent on my project.
         */
        echo '<h2>' . $what . '</h2>';
        echo '<pre>' . htmlspecialchars($debug, ENT_QUOTES) . '</pre>';

    }

}

class someClass {

    private $de;
    // private to this class to prevent accidental call
    // outside the class.

    public function __construct() {

           $this->de = new soapBug;
    }

    public function thatNeedsDebugging() {

        /* 
         * Simple enough to debug your client now no need to copy
         * the html block all over you can debug with just one line
         * of call all of them
         */
        $this->de->bug($client->request, 'Request'); // I grab this output string
        $this->de->bug($client->response, 'Response');
        $this->de->bug($client->debug_str, 'Debug');
    }
}
```